# I need to swap harddisk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu

I had some motherboard issues so i bought a cpu for seconds which has 500 gb hard disk with windows professional os. Now i need to swap this 500 gb hard disk with my older 1tb hard disk which has windows 7 ultimate but the configuration for the two cpus are different(processor etc). Is it possible to boot my older 1tb harddisk in this cpu? If so please guide me.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You cannot buy a cpu for seconds and it cannot contain an OS. Did you mean a second cpu in the form of a desktop/laptop? What did you try?

Comment: I guess that with swapping you mean switching/exchange? On this site swapping the harddisk means something else.

Comment: I think what you are really asking is if you can put the HDD with the OS on it coming from a differently configured computer into the machine you want to get up and running again. With Win7 that should not be a problem, XP would still have hiccuped heavily. You might have to provide some drivers to get it fully operational.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question is that you bought a second computer with a different cpu?
And you want to use another hard-drive instead of the one that came with the computer?

Yes, that is possible, shouldn't be a problem.
Just open both computers get the hard drive out and switch them, or put them both in one computer.